# Work with an access 2003 database with 2016 version

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a database made in access 2003, I bought recently Access 2016, I'll have any problem with access 2016 or I need to downgrade my Access version?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not have any problems. You can open and edit Access 2003 with Access 2016, and even create a database on Access 2016 and save it as an Access 2003 database.

Comment: There is a caveat; some VBA scripts work differently in different versions of Access. You may need to troubleshoot and rewrite if you have any.

Comment: I agree with Jeff Zeitlin. A lot of scripts in my old database in Access 97 broke when trying to open it in Access 2007. Not sure if it was just VBA.

Comment: @Pere Access 97 was reputed for compatibility issue. I think from 2003+ it's less problematic.